# Not able call Carousel frunction in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Trying to create an carousel with thumbnails. When click on thumbnail image it needs to call carousel function.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'react-bootstrap'

function changeSlide(){
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function () {
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
  try {
   var id = /-(\d+)$/.exec(id_selector)[1];
   console.log(id_selector, id);
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(parseInt(id));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
module.exports.changeSlide = changeSlide;
```

Now when click on thumbnail i'm getting console error

```
TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).carousel is not a function
 at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:21)
 at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
 at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-bootstrap` does not rely on jQuery and your components are powered by React instead of jQuery.

Bootstrap comes in two parts: CSS and JS. The JS portions are to handle user interaction with the components. Traditionally, people will use Bootstrap's CSS with:

1. Bootstrap JS which uses jQuery OR
2. react-bootstrap which uses React

Both jQuery and React aim to respond to user interaction and apply the corresponding DOM manipulations. You usually should not be mixing them together in a component.

You should be able to get it to work just by following the example code: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#carousels